# XML / XSL : xpath and condition when/otherwise

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a problem with my xsl transformation.

Here's the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<accounts>
  <account>
    <name>ryan</name>
    <pass>password</pass>
    <date></date>
    <numbers>
      <number>19</number>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
      <number>2</number>
    </numbers>
    <numbers>
      <number>20</number>
    </numbers>
  </account>
  <account>
    <name>lift</name>
    <pass>azerty</pass>
    <date>27/05/2015</date>
    <numbers>
    </numbers>
  </account>
</accounts>
```

Here's the XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="windows-1252"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:variable name="newline">
            <xsl:text/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <accounts>
                <xsl:for-each select="accounts/account">
                    <account>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::numbers)]">
                            <xsl:choose> 
                                <xsl:when test="count(*|text()[string-length(normalize-space(.))>0])"> 
                                    <xsl:copy> 
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
                                    </xsl:copy> 
                                </xsl:when> 
                                <xsl:otherwise> 
                                    <xsl:copy> 
                                        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute> 
                                    </xsl:copy> 
                                </xsl:otherwise> 
                            </xsl:choose>                       
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:call-template name="t_number"/>                    
                    </account>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </accounts>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="t_number" match="numbers">
            <xsl:choose> 
                <xsl:when test="count(number)"> 
                    <numbers>
                        <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number">
                            <number>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </number>
                        </xsl:for-each>                         
                    </numbers> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise> 
                    <numbers xsi:nil="true"></numbers>  
                </xsl:otherwise> 
            </xsl:choose> 
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's what i have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<accounts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <account>
        <name>ryan</name>
        <pass>password</pass>
        <date xsi:nil="true">
        </date>
        <numbers xsi:nil="true"></numbers>
    </account>
    <account>
        <name>lift</name>
        <pass>azerty</pass>
        <date>27/09/2012</date>
        <numbers xsi:nil="true"></numbers>
    </account>
</accounts>
```

And what i want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<accounts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <account>
        <name>ryan</name>
        <pass>password</pass>
        <date xsi:nil="true">
        </date>
        <numbers>
            <number>19</number>
            <number>2</number>
            <number>20</number>
        </numbers>
    </account>
    <account>
        <name>lift</name>
        <pass>azerty</pass>
        <date>27/09/2012</date>
        <numbers xsi:nil="true"></numbers>
    </account>
</accounts>
```

Can you help me? The count function is working in a weird way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context node for the expression

```
<xsl:when test="count(number)">
```

is wrong. When called via `<xsl:call-template name="t_number"/>` your still inside `account`. So,

```
<xsl:when test="count(numbers/number) gt 0">
```

should do the trick. (I'd prefer the "gt 0", because it's in my opinion more readable.)

**Edit:** As far I see, the template "t_numbers" is only called once and via `<xsl:call-template name="t_number"/>`. Probably, you'd better delete `match="numbers"` in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: the `gt` syntax was not yet available in XSLT 1.0 (OP uses 1.0), it is an XPath 2.0 feature, perhaps you meant `&gt;`, which can also be written as `>` (no need to escape)?

Comment: It works, thanks ! But why you prefer > or gt than > ? just a personal choice ?

Comment: @Abel I sometimes forget, what's XPath 2. You're right, > would do the job as well. @gon There are various ways to test, if a (child) node is present. Personally, I like: "Count nodes xy and return true if there are more than zero" (`count(number) > 0`)  more than "Return true if there is something to count" (`count(number)`) which is what you had. However, that's just personal taste.

Comment: @gon, about the difference between `gt` and `>`, it is subtle. Essentially, `>` will auto-convert both sides of the operand, while `gt` requires typed values. `@x > 1` will typically not fail, but unless you use a schema-aware processor, `@x gt 1` will fail, and you should write `xs:int(@x) > 1` or something similar to satisfy the type constraints of XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/accounts">
    <accounts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </accounts>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::numbers)]"/>
        <numbers>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="numbers/number">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="numbers/number"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </numbers>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="date[not(string())]">
    <date xsi:nil="true"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Note*:
*The template matching `"/accounts"` can be removed and the result will be semantically identical.*